# TextChanged want it to validate after the user has entered a date but it validates as the user is entering the date

Tags: c#, textbox, datetimepicker, textchanged

Hi Guys this must be a simple logic for most programmers but i am not able to figure it out.

I have 2 datetimepicker on my windows form 
datetimepicker 1 = fromdate
datetimepicker 2 = todate

the from date and to date i get from the below sql

```
   SELECT MIN(TransDate) AS mindate, MAX(TransDate) AS maxdate 
FROM dbo.EtimePunchDetail WHERE (EmpID = @empid)
```

fromdate = mindate and todate = maxdate

fromdate.mindate = mindate 
 todate.maxdate = maxdate ("So the user is only working with the selected date range")

i added two textboxes with search functionality that the user can enter the fromdate and todate into and it checks against the mindate and maxdate and if the user enters a date out of the range i set the message box to throw an error

I have an textbox changed even that has the following query:

```
      private void Min_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

              DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(Min.Text);

              if (date < DateTime.Parse(AvailableMin.Text))
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("The Date you entered is either out of range or an invalid format");
                }
              else
                {
                  FromDate.MinDate = date;
                  FromDate.Value = date;
                }
        }
private void Max_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(Max.Text);

         if (date > DateTime.Parse(AvailableMax.Text))
         {
            MessageBox.Show("The Date you entered is either out of range or an invalid format");
         }
         else
         {
            ToDate.MaxDate = date;
            ToDate.Value = date;
         }
         }
```

But as i change the text the textchanged event gets fired with the message and is not letting me change the date or it says it is an invalid date. i want to be able to enter a date and then the textchanged should check to see if the date entered is not inrange how can i do that??

here is a visual representation for what i am asking for:

[image]

**More Code on how i am getting the min and max date and the other things i am doing with those values i should have included this in my question before i apologize i thing the datetimepicker validation is interfering with the textbox validation**

**Min and Max Value**

```
private void mindateset() // fill the listbox of values of mindate and maxdate
{
if (Employee.SelectedValue != null)
  {
if (Employee.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim().Length > 0)
    {
try
     {
  using (MSSQL.SqlConnection connection = new MSSQL.SqlConnection(constr))
       {
   timepunchnew = new EtimeHistoryDataSet();
    connection.Open();
    using (MSSQL.SqlCommand command = new MSSQL.SqlCommand("SELECT MIN(TransDate) AS mindate, MAX(TransDate) AS maxdate FROM dbo.EtimePunchDetail WHERE (EmpID = @empid)", connection))
    {
   MSSQL.SqlParameter myminparam = new MSSQL.SqlParameter();
   myminparam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
   myminparam.ParameterName = "@empid";
   myminparam.Value = Employee.SelectedValue;
   command.Parameters.Add(myminparam);
   MSSQL.SqlDataAdapter myadapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
   myadapter.SelectCommand = command;
   myadapter.Fill(timepunchnew, "Mindate");
   AvailableMin.DataSource = timepunchnew.Mindate;
   AvailableMin.DisplayMember = "mindate";
   AvailableMax.DataSource = timepunchnew.Mindate;
   AvailableMax.DisplayMember = "maxdate";
   FromDate.MinDate = DateTime.Parse(AvailableMin.Text);
   FromDate.Value = FromDate.MinDate;
   ToDate.MaxDate = DateTime.Parse(AvailableMax.Text);
   ToDate.Value = ToDate.MaxDate;
   Min.Text = FromDate.MinDate.ToString("d");
   Max.Text = ToDate.MaxDate.ToString("d");
   }
}
}
catch (Exception) { /*Handle error*/ }

}
}

 }
```

**Validation on the datetimepicker values**

```
private void FromDate_ValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
         if (empchanging == false)
         {
          if (FromDate.Value > ToDate.Value)
           {
             // MessageBox.Show("From Date Cannot Be Greater Than To Date");
                 if (DialogResult.OK == MessageBox.Show("From Date Cannot Be Greater Than To Date"))
                 {
                  FromDate.MinDate = DateTime.Parse(AvailableMin.Text);
                  FromDate.Value = FromDate.MinDate;

                }
              }
          }
         }
      private void ToDate_ValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
       if (empchanging == false)
       {
       if (ToDate.Value < FromDate.Value)
       {
      //MessageBox.Show("To Date Cannot Be Less Than From Date");
        if (DialogResult.OK == MessageBox.Show("To Date Cannot Be Less Than From Date"))
         {
         ToDate.MaxDate = DateTime.Parse(AvailableMax.Text);
         ToDate.Value = ToDate.MaxDate;
        }
     }
    }
     }
```

**Validating Available date range for empty string**

```
private void AvailableMin_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (AvailableMin.Text == string.Empty)
  {
   textBox2.Visible = true;
  textBox2.Text = "There is no From Date available for this particular user";

}
else
{
 textBox2.Visible = false;
 }
    }

private void AvailableMax_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (AvailableMax.Text == string.Empty)
    {
      textBox1.Visible = true;
   textBox1.Text = "There is no To Date available for this particular user";
  }
  else
    {
   textBox1.Visible = false;
    }
    }
```

**I tried the below solution**

```
 private void Min_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  DateTime date; 
if (!DateTime.TryParse(Min.Text, out date))
       {
formerrorprovider.SetError(this.Min,"The Date you entered is in invalid format");
  }
   else if (date < DateTime.Parse(AvailableMin.Text))
 {
  formerrorprovider.SetError(this.Min, "The Date you entered is either out of range");
     }
    else 
   {
   formerrorprovider.SetError(this.Min, string.Empty);
    FromDate.MinDate = date;
    FromDate.Value = date;
     }
```

**it accepts the date i enter but is interfering with the datetimepicker validation.**

[image]
**PLZ HELP**

Comment: Do you want to validate the input only when the user tries to move focus to another control, i.e. when they have finished entering a value?

Comment: @HABO when they have finished entering the value, that is why even when i delete the 5 in the 2015 the message box pops up with the message and if i try to clear the text box each time the text changed then i get the error string was not recognized.

Comment: FWIW, I've generally found that it is friendlier to validate all of the input when the user says they're done, e.g. they click on `Run Report`. That way you don't have them playing the game of trying to figure out the order in which they must change fields, e.g. `From Date` must not be later than `To Date`, but if you want to change both then you may _have_ to change From first. They can cut'n'paste, adjust and fiddle to their heart's content. Sure, you might not allow characters other than digits in the Employee Bar Code during data entry, but that's not validation.

Comment: @HABO thats exactly what i did, i infact added two more textboxes that would store the textbox values that the user enters and made the visibility false and then validated against the available min and max values once the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as a possible UI solution: don't show a MessageBox if date is invalid but add an ErrorProvider control to Form and set errors description to Max and Min textboxes. Error provider will show Error icon if there are incorrect data and hide it when input is acceptable

```
private void Max_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DateTime date;

     if (!DateTime.TryParse(Max.Text, out date))
     {
        formErrorProvider.SetError(this.Max, "The Date you entered is in invalid format");
     }
     else if (date > DateTime.Parse(AvailableMax.Text))
     {
        formErrorProvider.SetError(this.Max, "The Date you entered is out of range");
     }
     else
     {
        formErrorProvider.SetError(this.Max, string.Empty);
        ToDate.MaxDate = date;
        ToDate.Value = date;
     }
}
```

Comment: Ash I tried your solution but everytime i clear the existing date i am getting String was not recognized as a valid DateTime error. the reason for the error is  DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(Max.Text);

Comment: @HackMaster: well, what do you want the code to do when the value has been cleared? You can use `TryParse()` instead of `Parse()` to catch the "invalid format" case; the code you're using will always throw an exception if the user enters something not parseable as a `DateTime`.

Comment: @HackMaster, I used your code basically. Modified my answer with TryParse

Comment: Ash, I think you want `!DateTime.TryParse(Max.Text, out date) ||...` instead of what you posted.

Comment: @ASh i have added other bits of the code i am also validate the fromdate and todate. and also tried your solution now it lets me add the date with out the message box popping up :) but it is not validating with the datetimepicker :(

Comment: @PeterDuniho i know that the functionality of text_changed is to fire when the text changes i just want to take the date the user enters in the text box compare with the range from the datetimepicker and pop a message box with error if not just set the datetimepicker to the value of the textbox.

Comment: @ASh your solution did the magic!! but it is interfering with my validation of the datetimepicker, since i am setting it equal to the datetimepicker as i change the date i am getting the messagebox from the datetimepicker

Answer (score 2):

Your code is doing exactly what you asked it to do: it is validating the value *any time the text has changed*.

If this is not the behavior you want, then don't do that!

You may prefer, for example, to validate the value on the [`Leave`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`LostFocus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) event. Alternatively, you can leverage the existing validation model in the `Control` class and put your validation in a method that is an event handler for the [`Validating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx) event (which is raised between the `Leave` and `LostFocus` events).

The other suggestion – to present the user feedback in a less disruptive way – is also a very good suggestion. That would be more user-friendly in general, at the possible expense of making the user feedback more subtle and easier for the user to overlook.

Comment: In addition to the lose focus event calling the validation, you could also use the text change event to start (or restart) a short (say, 3 seconds) timer which, when it eventually does expire after the user stops typing, it would call the validation function. That way, the user need not tab to or click on another control to have the contents of the one with the current focus validated. The timer's duration should be a balance between being so short that your problem still happens and so long that the user feels compelled to click on or tab to another control to force the validation.